# window.getSelection().toString() not working in Firefox (works in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla

When I highlight numbers on an `<input type="number">` in Chrome, `window.getSelection().toString()` successfully gives me the highlighted text.

But this is not so in Firefox; it is always blank. Does anyone know why? This is really confusing since [MDN getSelection documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) states it should work in Firefox 57.

Comment: Where are you running your code ?

Comment: With "blank" you mean an empty string? It's working fine for me testing it on this page. Does this only happen on a specific page?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you're using, along with the expected output?

Comment: Very strange bug. I can fix it width inpput text , but  not number.

Answer (score 4):

This is a firefox bug. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686

Very old one, not fixed yet.

I use the following code as workaround:

```
        function getSelectionText() {
            if (window.getSelection) {
                try {
                    var activeElement = document.activeElement;
                    if (activeElement && activeElement.value) {
                        // firefox bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686
                        return activeElement.value.substring(activeElement.selectionStart, activeElement.selectionEnd);
                    } else {
                        return window.getSelection().toString();
                    }

                } catch (e) {
                }
            } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
                // For IE
                return document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's still per specs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply